# What am I missing? ASP.NET Core 6 keycloak integration, authentication fails after successful login

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, keycloak, openid

Here is what I did: using my local keycloak server (thru docker), I created a realm, users, role and client with this setup :

[image]

I set up credentials and got secret key and stuff and that's it, I haven't set anything, no mappers, client scope, etc.

I did this as our other applications that is using other languages such as PHP or nodejs have similar settings.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    //Sets cookie authentication scheme
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(cookie =>
{
    //Sets the cookie name and maxage, so the cookie is invalidated.
    cookie.Cookie.Name = "keycloak.cookie";
    cookie.Cookie.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    cookie.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    cookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    //Use default signin scheme
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    //Keycloak server
    options.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("Keycloak")["ServerRealm"];
    //Keycloak client ID
    options.ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("Keycloak")["ClientId"];
    //Keycloak client secret
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("Keycloak")["ClientSecret"];

    //Keycloak .wellknown config origin to fetch config
    // options.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetSection("Keycloak")["Metadata"];
    //Require keycloak to use SSL
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");

    //Save the token
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    //Token response type, will sometimes need to be changed to IdToken, depending on config.
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    //SameSite is needed for Chrome/Firefox, as they will give http error 500 back, if not set to unspecified.
    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "https://schemas.scopic.com/roles"
    };

    Configuration.Bind("<Json Config Filter>", options);
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "http://localhost:13636/home";
        await Task.FromResult(0);
    };

});
```

Then I created a fresh ASP.NET Core MVC application and setup the OpenId options like so

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

My `HomeController` looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        bool value = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I access `localhost:13636/Privacy` to test, the Keycloak login page is triggered which is correct, but after successful login and a  redirect to `/home`, `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is false and it seems like the application doesn't know that authentication has been successful.

What needs to be done after this?

Or am I missing some configuration/settings/options?

Summary of what I did

1. Setup keycloak dashboard (created Realm, client, user and roles)
2. Setup a simple ASP.NET Core MVC application, pass openid options and controller.
3. The keycloak login page is triggered but authentication fail during test

Comment: Check if your asp.net core session cookie is not returned back to the client application after the call to /signin-oidc .... Usually it is a HTTPS and samesite issue.

Comment: also, do you really need the OnRedirectToIdentityProvider  handler?

Comment: @ToreNestenius thanks for the reply, how do i check if the core session cookie is returned back or not? what should ill be checking in dev tools? and if the session cookie is not returned what should i do next?

Comment: I would use a tool like https://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddler-classic to inspect the traffic between the client and keycloak, to identify if the cookies that is set, is returned back by the browser or not

Comment: what should i do if the correct cookies are not pass to the redirect URL? @ToreNestenius

Comment: se my answer below? and make sure you use HTTPS, does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to the AddCookie handler the following setting:

```
options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
```

To make sure the cookies are set with SameSite=none.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic: [Debugging cookie problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/)